# Loop macro and change ranges with each loop

Tags: vba, excel

I’m starting with a worksheet “Med” that has formulas/data/formatting in cells A4:P9.  I need to copy those cells to cell A10 (6 rows down).  I then need to fill in some of the cells from information in another worksheet “Data”.  I need to repeat this the same number of times as the count of Data!(A:A) -1  dropping down 6 rows each time I copy the information.

The data that I need to fill in comes from the Sheet "Data" and moves over one column for each copy in Sheet “Med”.

I have the code to make the first copy, but don’t have any idea where to go from here.  Looking at the code below the next copy would go to A16 (6 rows down from A10).

The ranges from the worksheet “Med” would also increase by 6 rows and the columns would stay the same.

The ranges from the worksheet “Data” would move over on column and the row numbers would stay the same.

Jordan

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim wsData As Worksheet 
    Dim wsMed As Worksheet 
    Set wsData = Sheets("Data") 
    Set wsMed = Sheets("Med")

    'Copy data set
    wsMed.Range("A4:P9").Copy wsMed.Range("A10") 'Set Premium Values
    wsMed.Range("M11").Value = wsData.Range("C20").Value
    wsMed.Range("M12").Value = wsData.Range("C21").Value
    wsMed.Range("M13").Value = wsData.Range("C22").Value
    wsMed.Range("M14").Value = wsData.Range("C23").Value 'Set Assumptions
    wsMed.Range("L11").Value = wsData.Range("C24").Value
    wsMed.Range("L12").Value = wsData.Range("C25").Value
    wsMed.Range("L13").Value = wsData.Range("C26").Value
    wsMed.Range("L14").Value = wsData.Range("C27").Value 
End Sub
```

Comment: How often does the code need to run? Do you always copy A4:P9 or does the second copy use other cells?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This macro runs the code three times

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Dim wsMed As Worksheet
    Set wsData = Sheets("Data")
    Set wsMed = Sheets("Med")
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, x As Integer

    i = 10
    j = 3


    'Copy data set
    For x = 1 To 3 ' run 3 times
        wsMed.Range("A4:P9").Copy wsMed.Cells(i, 1) 'Set Premium Values
        wsMed.Range("M" & i + 1).Value = wsData.Cells(20, j).Value
        wsMed.Range("M" & i + 2).Value = wsData.Cells(21, j).Value
        wsMed.Range("M" & i + 3).Value = wsData.Cells(22, j).Value
        wsMed.Range("M" & i + 4).Value = wsData.Cells(23, j).Value 'Set Assumptions
        wsMed.Range("L" & i + 1).Value = wsData.Cells(24, j).Value
        wsMed.Range("L" & i + 2).Value = wsData.Cells(25, j).Value
        wsMed.Range("L" & i + 3).Value = wsData.Cells(26, j).Value
        wsMed.Range("L" & i + 4).Value = wsData.Cells(27, j).Value
        i = i + 6
        j = j + 1
    Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  The code needs to run for whatever the count is across row 1 in the "data" worksheet minus 1.

Comment: I got it.  I added this in place of the 3.  I used cell A27 to do a count of row 1 in "Data".  I think there is a way to get the count within the code, but this works!!  Worksheets("Info").Range("A27").Value - 1